# Response::download() doesn't work in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to use this: Response::download() to make a download of a file, I'm using Laravel 4, here my code:

```
public function download_file($file)
{
      $file = 'myfile.pdf';

      //-- public/docs/myfile.pdf
      $path = public_path(). '/docs/' . $file;

      $headers = array(
        'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
      );

    return Response::download($path, $file, $headers);
}
```

The error I got: 
The file "C:\Users\myuser\Workbench\Web\sites\mysite\public/docs/myfile.pdf" does not exist

What did I went wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Make sure that the file do really exist !

Comment: Sure, there is in this path: public/docs/myfile.pdf. Thanks.

Comment: Try this `C:\Users\myuser\Workbench\Web\sites\mysite\public/docs/myfile.pdf` in the explorer !

Comment: Ok, I tried and I saw the error, my fault, I save the file with extension .pdf, that's the reason why not found. Many thanks!